# Problem with injective functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

$f_1:X\rightarrow Y$ , $f_2:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y\rightarrow Z$ are injective and $gf_1=gf_2$ then following is true: $f_1=f_2$

My initial proof is this. It's pretty straight forward. Is it correct?
$$gf_1=gf_2 \Leftrightarrow (gf_1)(x) = (gf_2)(x)\ \forall \ x \in Y \Rightarrow f_1(x)=f_2(x) \ \forall \ x\in X \Leftrightarrow f_1=f_2$$

Comment: It's a bit lacking in arguments, I'd say...

Comment: You should write $(gf_1)(x)$ instead of $y$.

Comment: $f_1,f_2$ are set on $X$ not on $Y$.

Comment: And change the $y$ to $x$ in $\forall y\in Y$.

Comment: I think it might be good to insert an extra step where you rewrite $(gf_1)(x)$ as $g(f_1(x))$ and similarly for $(gf_2)(x)$.  Also the "$\forall x \in X$" should be in _front_ of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that you should have "$\forall x\in X,$" rather than "$\forall x\in Y,$" it looks fine. You might want to point out that the implication in the middle is due to the fact that $g$ is injective.

In fact, we *only* require $g$ to be injective to get this result. There is no need for $f_1,f_2$ to be injective here. Moreover, you can show that the following are equivalent for any function $g:Y\to Z$:

- $g$ is injective.
- For any set $X$ and any functions $f_1,f_2:X\to Y$ such that $gf_1=gf_2,$ we have $f_1=f_2.$